# CSS3 Keyframes animation stopmotion image shaking

Tags: css, css-animations

I am in desperate need of help.

What im trying to do is the same thing mozolla did to the homepage of firefox for their firefox OS. The flaming fox.

Heres the demo of it: http://davidwalsh.name/demo/firefox-animation.php

And here is my animation, notice the wobble. The frames are spaced evenly.

http://jsfiddle.net/vSXcr/

Any ideas?

```
.bannerimg {
background: url(http://beresponsive.net/tcex/img/ani3.png) repeat-x;
width: 432px;
height: 537px;
animation: animate-kids 3s steps(32) infinite;
-webkit-animation: animate-kids 3s steps(32) infinite;
-moz-animation: animate-kids 3s steps(32) infinite;
}
@keyframes animate-kids {
0% {background-position: 0 0; }
100% {background-position: -13958px 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate-kids {
0% {background-position: 0 0; }
100% {background-position: -13958px 0;}
}
@-moz-keyframes animate-kids {
0% {background-position: 0 0; }
100% {background-position: -13958px 0;}
}

<div class="bannerimg"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wobbles because your total sprite width (13958px) does not evenly divide into the number of frames your animation is stepping through (32): `13958 / 32 = 436.1875`. This will cause the stepped value during the animation interpolation to be rounded by the browser, which causes the wobble. This also means the location of your illustration varies between cells.

If you look at David's demo, you'll see his animation is smooth because it divides evenly: `6864 / 44 = 156`

You'll need to space your frames out more so your total sprite width divides evenly into 32 frames: `32 * 437 = 13984`. Pad your sprite so that its width is 13984px and your frames should be evenly spaced at 437px.

Comment: Okay i redid the math to what you said, but i still get a shake. I updated the jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/vSXcr/

Comment: You didn't change anything... You need edit your sprite image making each of your 32 frames 437px wide so that your total sprite width will be 13984px. Then update your `.bannerimg` class setting `width: 437px;`

Comment: Your code is correct, but your sprite still isn't spaced evenly. [Here's a screenshot](http://drp.mk/i/NdXj) with guides spaced every 437px that shows why your cells are shifting. If you were to cut these all out an lay them on top of one another you'll see not all frames line up.

Comment: Ahh okay I see. Do you know if a script or method in photoshop to ensure they line up correctly? I currently snap function in photoshop and as you pointed out it is overlapping on the frames. Im sure there must be some tool that helps with this

Comment: This thread is now veering away from StackOverflow territory and into a Photoshop-specific discussion. I think this question has evolved into a separate discussion more suited for the [Graphic Design StackExchange portal](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ahh okay, well thank you very much for all of your help. Learned for future animations

Comment: On chrome 35 win 8 x64 is shaking [ even if dimension are outright ] everything else is OK so i think is only buq in chrom engine